# Redrawing a diode circuit in a clearer way

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes, integrated-circuit

I'm trying to redraw the circuit with nodal voltage circuit in a better way. Is my drawing right? Can I make it simpler? 
[image]

Redrawn as:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably better drawn this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBSjYzm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All currents (positive polarity) should flow from the top of the sheet towards the bottom. All signals should flow from the left side (inputs) of the sheet to the right side (outputs) of the sheet. The above schematic arranges all the diodes so that they point, correctly, from top towards bottom of the sheet.

The arrangement above doesn't say anything about which voltages are more positive or more negative. But if the diodes are active, then it is at least suggestive (as discussed at the bottom, below.) Which is the best you can hope for.

The circuit tells you immediately that \$V_O\$ is an output of interest. There is no particular need to show the (+) and (-) terminals for \$V_O\$, since it is already implied.

---

Assuming a fixed voltage drop for a diode, the following can be immediately determined from a casual examination now:

1. To be active, the path from \$V_1\$ to \$V_O\$ requires that it must be at least one diode drop ***above*** \$V_O\$. Otherwise, the path is inactive.
2. To be active, the path from \$V_2\$ to \$V_O\$ requires that it must be at least one diode drop ***below*** \$V_O\$. Otherwise, the path is inactive.
3. To be active, the path from \$V_3\$ to \$V_O\$ requires that it must be at least one diode drop ***below*** \$V_O\$. Otherwise, the path is inactive.
4. In all cases, there is a path from \$V_O\$ to ground via \$R_4\$.

Comment: thank you but analyzing your circuit is even harder for a 2nd year electrical engineering student. I need to make it simple to be able to apple kcl kvl etc to fina V0

Comment: @Joe It actually ***is*** simpler. I learned this technique from Tektronix when being taught ***drafting***, not electronics. I've never taken a single course in electronics, in fact. And as someone just learning to draft circuits, I completely understood the approach. So it's not at all hard for a 2nd yr. And as you get into harder circuits, you'll find the process and technique invaluable. KVL/KCL is trivial to apply, too. It doesn't make that any more difficult (and perhaps easier.)

Comment: @Joe - KCL says the sum of currents flowing into and out of a node equals zero. Current [(V1-Vo-V_diode)/R1] flows into node Vo through D1. Current flows out of node Vo through R4, D2, and D3. You can express those currents in terms of V2,V3,Vo, V_diode, and resistances. jonk's drawing makes this easier for me to see. It takes a while to develop this kind of intuition, but you will get there.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+60+5+50%0Ad+288+304+288+256+1+0.805904783%0Ar+288+208+288+256+0+5000%0AR+288+208+288+176+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0AR+336+208+336+176+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+336+208+336+256+0+10000%0Ad+336+304+336+256+1+0.805904783%0AR+240+208+240+176+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+240+208+240+256+0+1000%0Ad+240+256+240+304+1+0.805904783%0Aw+336+304+288+304+0%0Aw+288+304+240+304+0%0Ar+288+336+288+384+0+1000%0Aw+288+304+288+336+0%0Ag+288+384+288+400+0%0Aw+288+336+336+336+0%0Aw+288+384+336+384+0%0Ap+336+336+336+384+0+0%0A) is how **I** would prefer it. These answers will be all over the place.. everyone got their own opinions.

[image]

And yeah, instead of \$5 V\$ it should say \$V_1\$, \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$. And instead of \$1 k\$, \$5 k\$ and \$10 k\$ it should say \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$.

But schematic wise, this is how I would prefer it. Ground at the bottom, things that are in parallel, in parallel, positive sources coming from the top.

---

I do have to say that the way you redrew it actually made it harder for me to understand the schematic. It went from being "*hmm.. okay this could be tidied up*" to "*oh this looks like an exam question, I must untangle this*"